# CSS background image combine pixel ratio and width

Tags: html, ios, css, image

How do I combine width and pixel ratio in a media query for responsive images in CSS?

I have 4 cases for each image: Medium width screens, Medium width & pixel ratio 2 (retina display), Large width, and large width retina. So far I can only get either widths or pixel ratios to trigger, but not both at the same time.

http://codepen.io/sinrise/pen/NNgVLL

I'm using a SASS mixin to save me some typing:

```
$screen-md: 1200;
$screen-lg: 1500px;

@mixin respImg($image) {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://quantumtribal.com/test/#{$image}_md.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  p { height: 500px; }

  @media
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    { background-image: url("http://quantumtribal.com/test/#{$image}_md@2x.jpg"); }

  @media
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-md) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
    { background-image: url("http://quantumtribal.com/test/#{$image}_med.jpg"); }


  @media
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
    { background-image: url("http://quantumtribal.com/test/#{$image}_lg@2x.jpg"); }

  @media
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
    only screen and (min-width: $screen-lg) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
    { background-image: url("http://quantumtribal.com/test/#{$image}_lg.jpg"); }
}

#testImage { @include respImg("test"); }
```

I know, I could be using srcset and/or `<picture>` in the HTML but because of the nature of my layout I'm forced to use background images in the project.